# Dense Rank Skip Null Values Partition by Multiple

Tags: sql, null, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, partition, dense-rank

I have a table that looks like below:

```
       Date      User      Product
 11/15/2019       123         NULL
 11/21/2019       123            A
 11/21/2019       123            A
 11/23/2019       123            B
```

I want to run a dense_rank function that will skip the null values.

Below is what I currently have:

```
CASE WHEN PRODUCT IS NOT NULL 
THEN DENSE_RANK() 
OVER (PARTITION BY USER ORDER BY DATE ASC) 
ELSE 1 
END DENSE_RANK_OUTPUT
```

My current output:

```
       Date      User      Product     DENSE_RANK_OUTPUT
 11/15/2019       123         NULL                     1
 11/21/2019       123            A                     2
 11/21/2019       123            A                     2
 11/23/2019       123            B                     3
```

My desired output is:

```
       Date      User      Product        DESIRED_OUTPUT
 11/15/2019       123         NULL                     1
 11/21/2019       123            A                     1
 11/21/2019       123            A                     1
 11/23/2019       123            B                     2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are close.  Just use another key in the `partition by`:

```
(CASE WHEN PRODUCT IS NOT NULL 
      THEN DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY USER, (PRODUCT IS NOT NULL) ORDER BY DATE ASC) 
      ELSE 1 
 END) as DENSE_RANK_OUTPUT
```